# should we use banned instead of banning? what's incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

In 1971, US government not only put warnings on cigarette packs, but also banning TV advertising of cigarettes.

Comment: "Banned" would be correct there.  The sentence is in the past tense; the verbs are "put" and "ban", and the past tenses are "put" and "banned" respectively.  (Also, if you haven't yet checked it out, please visit our sister site, [ell.se].)

Comment: okay thank you i will have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I guess, banned should be used in that sentence. Banning is looking more present tense in this context.

Correct:- In 1971, the US government not only put warnings on cigarette packs but also banned TV advertising of cigarettes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be ‘banned’, unless you’ve cut the sentence short.